# Azure error - A default document is not configured for the requested URL, and directory browsing is not enabled on the server

Tags: node.js, azure, express, azure-web-app-service

I just recently tried to deploy my node.js application to azure app service but when I try and load the '/' route it says "You do not have permission to view this directory or page." . When I check the log stream for errors it says:

> *"A default document is not configured for the requested URL, and directory browsing is not enabled on the server. Things you can try:
> If you do not want to enable directory browsing, ensure that a default
> document is configured and that the file exists. Enable directory
> browsing using IIS Manager. Open IIS Manager. In the Features view,
> double-click Directory Browsing. On the Directory Browsing page, in
> the Actions pane, click Enable. Verify that the
> configuration/system.webServer/directoryBrowse@enabled attribute is
> set to true in the site or application configuration file"*

I don't understand why it says a default document is not configured. My express.js app handles the '/' route by rendering the login view. So there will be no need have a default document.

Comment: If possible, can you share your repo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message you provided ("A default document is not configured for the requested URL, and directory browsing is not enabled on the server") can occur when deploying your applications to Azure Web Apps on Windows.

So, deploying your application to Azure App Service on Linux could potentially avoid the specific error related to default document configuration that you mentioned.

I tried deploying NodeJS application to Azure app service.

This is my project structure :

```
my-app
├── views/
│ └── login.ejs
├── node_modules/
├── index.js
├── package.json
└── package-lock.json
```

**Index.js**:

```json
const  express  =  require('express');
const  path  =  require('path');
const  app  =  express();
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
res.render('login');
});
const  PORT  =  process.env.PORT  ||  3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

**login.ejs**:

```json
<!DOCTYPE  html>
<html  lang="en">
<head>
<meta  charset="UTF-8">
<meta  name="viewport"  content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Login Page</h1>
<p>Welcome to nodejs application :)</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the local output:

[image]

While creating web app, select operating system as **linux**.
[image]

For deployment,

Select the Azure logo on the taskbar in Visual Studio Code to open the Azure window.

Here are the steps:

1.Select your Azure subscription.

2.Then, select your created web app

3.Right-click on the web app

4. Here you will see the Deploy to Web Application option.

[image]

[image]

To view the website in the browser, right-click the project  and select **Browse Site**.

[image]

Here's the output:

[image]